# Scrollview not scrolling

Tags: android

I'm using a scroll view which is having only one child linearlayout.
Linearlayout contains listview and some other items also, but only listview is scrolling. what should i do ?
Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/beco_white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/view_switcher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:background="@drawable/dark_blue_round_corner"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                    android:text="Login to beCo"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_sign_up"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                    android:text="Create New Account"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:id="@+id/image_profile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp88"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp88"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
                    fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/no_profile_pic"
                    fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
                    fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/white"
                    fresco:roundingBorderWidth="@dimen/dp2" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_profile"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                    android:text="John Doe"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_profile"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_profile"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                    android:text="johndoe@mail.com"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_edit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_profile"
                    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                    android:text="Edit Profile"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ViewSwitcher>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_200" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any one please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using only with the listview. ie., removing **scrollview**, and by using **headerview** for the **listview**
**Xml code** for **listview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/beco_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_200" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/dp1"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**xml code** for **headerview** of **listview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/view_switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp40"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_blue_round_corner"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp16">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                android:text="@string/new_to_beco"
                android:textColor="@color/beco_white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_up"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/beco_primary"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_background">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/image_profile"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/no_profile_pic"
            fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
            fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/white"
            fresco:roundingBorderWidth="@dimen/dp2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_profile"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_profile"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_profile"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="John Doe"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
            android:text="johndoe@mail.com"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/action_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/email"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 1):

Never put A `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. It is a bad practice and it defeats the purpose of having a `ListView`. Who wants two scrollable areas on a screen anyway?

Instead add a header or footer view on your listView depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html it states that scrollview should never be used with listview there may be a conflict between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

changes:

1. Make your inner linearlayout wrap into `Scrollview`
2. Apply `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `scrollview`
3. End the `scrollview` before `Listview` as both can not be applied together

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ```

   ```
   <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:fillViewport="false">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

           <ViewSwitcher
               android:id="@+id/view_switcher"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="125dp"
                   android:background="@android:color/white"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                   <Button
                       android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
                       android:layout_width="150dp"
                       android:layout_height="40dp"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp20"
                       android:background="@drawable/dark_blue_round_corner"
                       android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                       android:text="Login to beCo"
                       android:textAllCaps="false"
                       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                       android:textSize="14sp" />

                   <Button
                       android:id="@+id/button_sign_up"
                       android:layout_width="150dp"
                       android:layout_height="40dp"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20"
                       android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                       android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                       android:text="Create New Account"
                       android:textAllCaps="false"
                       android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                       android:textSize="14sp" />


               </LinearLayout>

               <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="125dp"
                   android:background="@android:color/white">

                   <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                       android:id="@+id/image_profile"
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/dp88"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/dp88"
                       android:layout_gravity="left"
                       android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
                       fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                       fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/no_profile_pic"
                       fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
                       fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/white"
                       fresco:roundingBorderWidth="@dimen/dp2" />


                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/user_name"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_profile"
                       android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                       android:text="John Doe"
                       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                       android:textSize="25sp" />

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/email"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_profile"
                       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_profile"
                       android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                       android:text="johndoe@mail.com"
                       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                       android:textSize="14sp" />

                   <Button
                       android:id="@+id/button_edit"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_profile"
                       android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                       android:text="Edit Profile"
                       android:textAllCaps="false"
                       android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

               </RelativeLayout>

           </ViewSwitcher>
       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>


   <View
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:background="@color/grey_200" />

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

> `NestedScrollView` is just like `ScrollView`, but it supports acting
>   as both a nested scrolling `parent` and `child` on both new and old
>   versions of Android.

See the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

**Update your XML as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/beco_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_scorll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

            <ViewSwitcher
                android:id="@+id/view_switcher"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp20"
                        android:background="@drawable/dark_blue_round_corner"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                        android:text="Login to beCo"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_sign_up"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20"
                        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                        android:text="Create New Account"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">

                    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp88"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp88"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
                        fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/no_profile_pic"
                        fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
                        fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/white"
                        fresco:roundingBorderWidth="@dimen/dp2" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/user_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_profile"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                        android:text="John Doe"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_profile"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_profile"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
                        android:text="johndoe@mail.com"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_edit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_profile"
                        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                        android:text="Edit Profile"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </ViewSwitcher>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_200" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```